# Android: Paging on custom class created from HorizontalScrollView is not smooth

Tags: android, horizontalscrollview, pager, infinite

I am trying to create an infinite pager from a HorizontalScrollView.

It does infinitely scroll by continuously rearranging the children views as needed, but once it has to start moving the views (adding to the left or the right) it is no longer scrolling smoothly. I am trying to figure out how to get it to scroll to the next page smoothly even after it changes the child position.

Here is the class as I have it so far:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.HorizontalScrollView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class PagerInfinite extends HorizontalScrollView {
    private LinearLayout contents;
    private Map<Integer, Integer> childWidths =  new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    private int childSpacing = 0;
    private int activePageIndex = 1;
    private float oldX = 0f;
    private float oldY = 0f;
    private boolean firstScroll = true;

public PagerInfinite(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.contents = new LinearLayout(context);
    this.contents.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    this.addView(this.contents);
    setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    for (int i = 0; i < this.contents.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = this.contents.getChildAt(i);
        int width = child.getWidth();
        if(width != 0) {
            this.childWidths.put(i, width);
        }
    }
    if(this.childWidths.size() > 0 && this.firstScroll) {
        this.smoothScrollTo(this.getActivePageOffset(), 0);
        this.firstScroll = false;
    }
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

@Override
protected float getLeftFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0.0f;
}

@Override
protected float getRightFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return 0.0f;
}

public void addPage(View child) {
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.setMargins(0, 0, this.childSpacing, 0);
    child.setLayoutParams(params);
    if(this.contents.getChildCount() <= 1) {
        this.contents.addView(child);
    } else if(this.contents.getChildCount() <= 2) {
        this.contents.addView(child, 0);
    } else {
        View last = this.contents.getChildAt(0);
        this.contents.removeView(last);
        this.contents.addView(last);
        this.contents.addView(child, 0);
    }
    this.contents.requestLayout();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean result = super.onTouchEvent(event);

    switch(event.getAction()) {
        case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):
            this.oldX = event.getX();
            this.oldY = event.getY();
            break;
        case(MotionEvent.ACTION_UP):
            float newX = event.getX();
            float newY = event.getY();
            float deltaX = newX - this.oldX;
            float deltaY = newY - this.oldY;

            // Use deltaX and deltaY to determine the direction
            if(Math.abs(deltaX) > Math.abs(deltaY)) {
                if(deltaX > 0) {
                    // right
                    if(this.activePageIndex <= 1) {
                        this.buildLeft();
                    } else {
                        this.activePageIndex -= 1;
                    }
                } else {
                    // left
                    if(this.activePageIndex >= this.contents.getChildCount() - 2) {
                        this.buildRight();
                    } else {
                        this.activePageIndex += 1;
                    }
                }
            }
            this.smoothScrollTo(this.getActivePageOffset(), 0);
            break;
    }

    return result;
}

private void buildLeft() {
    View view = this.contents.getChildAt(this.contents.getChildCount() - 1);
    this.contents.removeView(view);
    this.contents.addView(view, 0);
}

private void buildRight() {
    View view = this.contents.getChildAt(0);
    this.contents.removeView(view);
    this.contents.addView(view);
}

private int getActivePageOffset() {
    Log.d(LCHApplication.TAG, "ActiveIndex = " + this.activePageIndex);
    if(this.activePageIndex == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(this.activePageIndex == this.contents.getChildCount() - 1) {
        return this.contents.getWidth();
    }
    int offset = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> entry : this.childWidths.entrySet()) {
        if(entry.getKey() < this.activePageIndex) {
            offset += entry.getValue() + this.childSpacing;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    offset += (this.childWidths.get(this.activePageIndex) / 2);
    offset -= (LCHApplication.instance.width / 2);
    return offset;
}

public boolean hasPage(View v) {
    return this.contents.indexOfChild(v) != -1;
}

public void removePage(View v) {
    int index = this.contents.indexOfChild(v);
    this.contents.removeView(v);
    this.childWidths.remove(index);
}

public int getCurrentPageIndex() {
    return this.activePageIndex;
}

public int getPageCount() {
    return this.contents.getChildCount();
}

public void removeAllPages() {
    this.contents.removeAllViews();
    this.childWidths = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
}

public void cycle() {
    if(this.activePageIndex < this.contents.getChildCount() - 1) {
        this.activePageIndex += 1;
    } else {
        this.activePageIndex = 0;
    }
    this.smoothScrollTo(this.getActivePageOffset(), 0);
}

public int getChildSpacing() {
    return this.childSpacing;
}

public void setChildSpacing(int spacing) {
    this.childSpacing = spacing;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its too late but I believe my answer may helpful to somebody else who has same issue.

Sample project with infinite pages - with page swipe effect

https://github.com/UdaySravanK/USK_APIs